# How to extend OracleCursor class from cx_Oracle

Tags: python, oop, cx-oracle

Using Python 2.7.12 and package `cx_Oracle` I'm trying to create an extended class of the what the package call [OracleCursor](http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cursor.html). I simply want to inherit the methods from the superclass and extend with some custom methods.

First I get the `OracleCursor` by

```
import cx_Oracle

conn = cx_Oracle.connect(username, password, dsn)
cursor = conn.cursor()
```

and I then have the following

```
>>> type(cursor)Out[6]:
OracleCursor

>>> isinstance(cursor, cx_Oracle.Cursor)
True
```

One would think that it is achieved by

```
class ExtendedCursor(cx_Oracle.Cursor):

    def hello_world(self):
        print('Hello world')


extended = ExtendedCursor(cursor)
```

but I get `TypeError: argument 1 must be cx_Oracle.Connection, not OracleCursor`. To me that error doesn't make sense. Also, I can't use `OracleCursor` as my superclass since it isn't recognized as a class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cursor is returned from the Connection object. You need to create a custom connection that returns your ExtendedCursor.

```
import cx_Oracle as cxo

class MyCursor(cxo.Cursor):
    def helloWorld(self):
        print "helloWorld"

class MyConnection(cxo.Connection):
    def cursor(self):
        return MyCursor(self)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    conStr = '<user>/<password>@127.0.0.1:1521/xe'
    db = MyConnection(conStr)
    c = db.cursor()

    print c

    c.execute('select 1+1 from dual')
    print(c.fetchall())

    c.helloWorld()
```

returns:

```
<__main__.MyCursor on <__main__.MyConnection to ...@127.0.0.1:1521/xe>>
[(2,)]
helloWorld
```