# How to extend cx_oracle sys_refcursor Curor class

Tags: python, oop, cx-oracle

I'm trying to extend a cursor which is created when a procedure is returning sys_refcursor. Solution [How to extend OracleCursor class from cx_Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41037363/how-to-extend-oraclecursor-class-from-cx-oracle) works for connection.cursor() but not for sys_refcursor.

```
import cx_Oracle as cxo

class MyCursor(cxo.Cursor):
    def helloWorld(self):
        print "helloWorld"

class MyConnection(cxo.Connection):
    def cursor(self):
        return MyCursor(self)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    conStr = 'ants/<password>'
    db = MyConnection(conStr)
    c = db.cursor()
    c.execute("""
        create or replace procedure cx_test_cursor(
            val4 out sys_refcursor
        ) is
        begin
            open val4 for
                select 1 a from dual union all
                select 2 from dual;
        end;
    """)

    result = c.callproc('ants.cx_test_cursor', [c.var(cxo.CURSOR)])
    c.execute('drop procedure cx_test_cursor')
    print result
    result[0].helloWorld()
```

result

```
[<cx_Oracle.Cursor on <__main__.MyConnection to user ants@local>>]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cx_test2.py", line 32, in <module>
    result[0].helloWorld()
AttributeError: 'cx_Oracle.Cursor' object has no attribute 'helloWorld'
```

Any ideas how to extend this cursor?

Comment: From https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/issues/111#issuecomment-344175470 : "There's a typo in stackoverflow example, helloWorld() not hellowWorld()"

Comment: I just corrected the typo.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with cx_Oracle 6 and higher, only.

Comment: that would be great!

Comment: This is now possible with cx_Oracle 6.x. Apologies for the delay in letting you know about this!